# Best way to test performance of various languages & frameworks

Tags: algorithm, performance-testing

I want to perform some empirical trade-off's to assess the performance of applications written in a number of different languages on a Linux platform.  Are there standard algorithms that typically used for this purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Some people](http://shootout.alioth.debian.org/gp4/) say there are, although I would argue about the "rightness" of the code in some of the tests on that site.